# pandas to_sql gives conversion errors even after specifiying dtype

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a program which imports data from an Excel to SQL tables. I need to do this for *several hundred* files, so I need to have a general approach.

I'm using SQLAlchemy to import my data frame to SQL Server, but the column ProductCode causes an issue. The first 1000 or so rows are integers, so SQL Alchemy identifies the data type as a integer. There are however some nvarchar values which causes an conversion error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AOE1' to data type int` when creating the table in SQL Server.

[image]

What I have tried is to specify that the column ProductCode should be nvarchar, but the error still persists. I can't write a dtype argument for all columns as I don't know how the structure of the Excel files before importing them to a data frame.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

sqlcon = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + serverName + '/' + databaseName + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server')

xl2 = pd.read_excel(fullPath, sheet_name=sheetName, header=None)
xl2.to_sql(tableName,schema='dbo',con=sqlcon, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype={'ProductCode': sa.types.NVARCHAR})
```

I've tried to go into Excel, and copy the name of the column there in case there was blank spaces or something in the column name, but it wasn't.

I still get the same error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AOE1' to data type int` though. Can I specify the dtype of a single column (leaving the others to be identified by SqlAlchemy?) or can I force SqlAlchemy to base its data type identifier by many more values (so I can capture the nvarchar values)?

**EDIT**

I've gone into the Excel file and sorted the table by the ProductCode column to have it start with the nvarchar values. It did not help.

I've tried to "restart variables" in Jupyter notebook in case the data type values has been cached. It did not work.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/b41229e43a59bd93a949c989de5133f1) works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing likely stems from a misunderstanding of how `dtype` works at different stages of your code. Here's a more explicit explanation:

When reading from Excel with `pd.read_excel`, you can specify the `dtype` to control how `pandas` reads that Excel column. Doing this helps `pandas` interpret the data correctly right from the start:

```
xl2 = pd.read_excel(fullPath, sheet_name=sheetName, dtype={'ProductCode': 'object'})
```

As another option, before writing to SQL, you could convert the column to `string`. This aligns with your intent to store the data as `nvarchar` in SQL Server:

```
xl2['ProductCode'] = xl2['ProductCode'].astype('object')
```

The `dtype` you specify in `to_sql` guides `SQLAlchemy` on how to create the SQL Server column:

```
xl2.to_sql(tableName, schema='dbo', con=sqlcon, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype={'ProductCode': sa.types.NVARCHAR})
```

Your `dtype` setting in `to_sql()` alone will not solve the issue because `SQLAlchemy` relies on `pandas`' dtype for columns you haven't explicitly set.

**For a more general approach**, if you're reading the Excel file in chunks, try using a larger chunk size to help pandas better infer the correct dtype for each column.

Comment: I tried the `xl2['ProductCode'] = xl2['ProductCode'].astype(str)` approach and it worked! Unfortunately it seems to give errors when trying to perform that while reading a file which does not contain a column ProductCode (I solved this using if statements for now). I don't read the rows in chunks. Yes, the column names are set in between. It is a consequence of the files being so different. Essentially I put the first row which does not contain any NaNs to be the header row.

Comment: Glad I could help!